# File download issue with Blazor server and Brave

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor-server-side, brave

When I try to create and download a file from memory with Blazor server it works without issue in both Edge and Chrome.

But if I try the same thing in Brave I´m getting this:

```
Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given).'.
```

EDIT:
I should add that the download window does open in Brave and the file is being downloaded correctly. The websocket error occurs immediatly afterwards.

This is the js function I tested it with.

```
function myFunction() {
    let utf8Encode = new TextEncoder();
    let myBuffer = utf8Encode.encode("abc")

    var blob = new Blob([myBuffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "test.txt";
    link.click();
}
```

Which I call from the index.razor of the WeatherForecast template (.Net 6)

```
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("myFunction");
```

I tried running the server in IIS or Docker instead, same result. Is there a way to get more information about the websocket error?

Comment: It could be  a security aspect on `Brave` browser that is preventing this behavior to happen. Have you tried this with other browsers to see if the outcome is the same?

Comment: In another situation, I have had to fully qualify the path name of the rest call. Don't know if that applies...but...

Comment: @RahulSharma I´ve tried Edge, Chrome and FireFox so far and none of them have the same issue. I tried giving the page every permission available in Brave and also deactivated Brave shield and all my extensions. To no avail.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Do you mean in the download attribute? What would that look like, since the file doesn´t really exist in a file system?

Comment: @noel Maybe this could shed some light on your issue: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/15410

Comment: It doesn't apply. NVM. :-/